# Segmentation Fault related to Pointer in c

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
        char *s="Hello";
        *s="World";
        printf("%s\n",s);
}
```

Why does the above program result in a segmentation fault?

Comment: on my machine it doesn't even compile

Comment: Try compiling with your warning flags on, such as `-Wall` if you're in GCC.  That will give you clues.

Comment: In addition to trying to overwrite a string literal, it is also an error to call a variadic function without a variadic declaration for it.

Comment: Why are you re-posting the exact same question?

Comment: Don't ask duplicates like this again. Actually, you can't now....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    char *s="Hello"; // makes 's' point to a constant
    *s="World";      // modifies what 's' points to
    printf("%s\n",s);
}
```

The first line of code makes `s` point to a constant. The second line tries to modify what `s` points to. So you are trying to modify a constant, which you can't do because a constant is ... well ... constant.

Answer (score 2):

because `*s` is a `char` not a `char*`(string)

Comment: is this related to dangling pointers??

Answer (score 2):

```
char *s="Hello";
```

declares a pointer to a string literal `"Hello"`.  This may exist in read-only memory so the line

```
*s="World";
```

is results in undefined behaviour.  A crash is a valid (and useful) form of undefined behaviour.

Either of the following alternatives would work

```
const char* s = "Hello";
s="World";
printf("%s\n",s);

char s[16] = "Hello";
strcpy(s, "World";)
printf("%s\n",s);
```

Comment: Isn't the issue here that `*s` is a `char`, not a string?

Comment: That'd cause a warning/error at compile time.  An segfault at run time will be coming from the attempt to write (the address of a different string literal) to the read-only location pointer to by `s`.

Answer (score 1):

`s` points to static (global) memory when it is created.  You cannot reassign to that memory at run-time, hence, the crash.

Comment: can u explain little more about memory????

Comment: The compiler sets aside special memory locations for this type of statically allocated string.  When you call `*s = "another string"` you are trying to access that memory which is likely read-only.  Behavior is undefined in this case.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy we can re-assign but we can't rewrite.

Comment: You could legitimately say `s = "another string"`, however.

Comment: u mean static memory as read only memory???

Comment: Yes.  Allocated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`*s` is the first char of the string, so assigning string to character makes error.

If you want to assing string use `s = "world"`

```
int main()
{
    char *s="Hello";
    s="World";
    printf("%s\n",s);
}
```

now try it will work.

char `*s="hello";` Here `s` is in readonly location. So we can assign another string, but cannot rewrite new string.

```
s = "hello"; //work
strcpy(s, "hello"); //segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

The statement

```
*s = "World";
```

*dereferences* `s`, which gives you the first character of the string `"Hello"`, or `'H'`.  So you're trying to assign a pointer value (the address of the string "World") to a single `char` object (the first character of the `"Hello"` string literal).

But...

On some systems (such as yours, apparently), string literals are stored in a read-only data segment, and attempting to modify read-only memory will lead to a runtime error on some systems.  Hence the crash.

To change `s` to *point* to the "World" string literal, simply drop the dereference:

```
s = "World";
```

Answer (score 1):

*s is the same as s[0]. s[0] has room to store a single character; in this case a 'W'.

There's not room to store the location of "World" in that character.

That's why you're getting a segmentation fault.